# Not able to access image stored in Storage folder in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to access an image in the url which is stored in the /storage folder.

Image Stored Path:

```
Project/storage/app/public/default.png
```

According to Laravel 5.5 docs, your publicly accessible files should be put in directory

```
storage/app/public
```

So I did the same, but when I try to access the image as:

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/default.png
```

then it doesn't work.

I tried the following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

but it throws an error:

> The "public/storage" directory already exists.

Comment: try `http://localhost:8000/default.png`

Comment: You can access all public path using /* like: `http://localhost:8000/default.png`

Comment: @HirenGohel yes i tried the same, but it doesn't work

Comment: You can pass full path of Image file like this,
http://localhost:8000/[Project Name]/storage/app/public/default.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `php artisan storage:link`

Then you can access all public path using /* like:

`http://localhost:8000/default.png`

Above command allow you to get images directly from public path!

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I tried the same: it through an error: The "public/storage" directory already exists

Comment: Now try to run url with your localhost. What error you got?

Comment: Try with: `http://localhost:8000/storage/app/public/default.png` Not sure but may be it works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156900/discussion-between-amrinder-singh-and-hiren-gohel).

Comment: oh sorry by mistake
i have accepted your answer now
okay there is a small issue i got.
On localhost i am able to access the image as: 
localhost:8000/storage/… 

but on live serve it's accessable as: 
13.57.71.20/storage/app/… 

Any idea?

Comment: Have you run that command on server? Also, you can Unaccept my answer also if you want it!

Comment: yes i did, and about accepting answer then you deserve it :)

Comment: Sorry, no idea!

Answer (score 16):

As for 2019, if any of you got this error:

"The "public/storage" directory already exists."

Then go to your public folder and delete the "storage" file.

Once you do it, run again the "php artisan storage:link" and it will work now

Answer (score 10):

The best way to do it is to first remove the symlink by running a code that will remove storage from the public folder first like so:

```
$ rm public/storage
```

then rerun the symlink code again

```
$ php artisan storage:link
```

You will see that afterwards the public/storage folder will reappear and will be updated

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting storage folder inside app/public/storage than run the command(`php artisan storage:link`) again and than you can access file using this path

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/<folder_name_if_folder_exists>/<file_name>.<extension>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access files inside storage folder directly as you tried. First you have to create a symbolic link of your storage "public" folder to your real "public" folder.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Try again after the command.

**NOTE:** If you are using windows open **command line** (cmd, git bash...) **as admin** to avoid errors.

Comment: I tried the same: it through an error: The "public/storage" directory already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try Deleting the storage Folder in the Public Directory and then Run This Command
"php artisan storage:link" then try it.

Answer (score 0):

**Sep 2019**

What's working for me:

- SSH into your homestead VM
- cd into your project folder
- php artisan storage:link (As Admin in your terminal)
- Run successfully I don't see a /storage folder in my /public dir
- Access images via blade using storage/ in the url eg. "storage/{{ $post->image }}"

If you run into any errors:

- rm -rf public/storage
- php artisan storage:link (As Admin in your terminal)